# java 8 getting timeZone from zonedLocalTime

Tags: date, datetime, java-8, localdate, zoneddatetime

I am writing a helper method that takes String representation of date and returns TimeZone

for example:

```
input: 2017-11-02T09:30:00-07:00
output : "America/Los_Angeles"
```

(Here the input is PST. I am using UTC offset of -7:00)

```
Here is my method
 public static String getTimeZone(final String date) {
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);

        String timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(zonedDateTime.getZone()).getAvailableIDs()[0];
        System.out.println(timezone);
        return timezone;
    }
```

when I pass in the above date, I get `Africa/Abidjan` which is totally incorrect.

I prefer "America/Los_Angeles" but atleast something that is correct. Here what I get is totally wrong in the sense, that time in Abidjan and Los_Angeles are very different.

what is the right way to get here?

Comment: Something’s gone wrong in this thread. When you can use the modern Java date and time API (including `ZonedDateTime`), I strongly believe there’s no point in also using the outdated `TimeZone` class. Prefer the modern `ZoneId`. Its static `getAvailableZoneIds` method will give you the available time zones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here my proposition :

```
public static String getTimeZone(final String date) {
    final ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(date,DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
    final TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(zonedDateTime.getZone());
    return  Arrays.stream(TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(timeZone.getRawOffset())).peek(System.out::println).findFirst().get();
}
```

Here the output

```
//America/Boise
```

Comment: why is Boise? I expect it to be Los_Angeles.

Comment: The list of the zones with the same time zone is sorted by name, so the first one at the list is America/Boise.

Answer (score 1):

`TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` is a **static** method and just returns all the known ids for every zone.

You can use `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(int rawOffset)` which returns the ids for a given millisecond offset.

For your example date/time

```java
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(zonedDateTime.getZone());
for (final String id : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(tz.getRawOffset())) {
  System.out.println("id " + id);
}
```

gives:

```
id America/Boise
id America/Cambridge_Bay
id America/Chihuahua
id America/Creston
id America/Dawson_Creek
id America/Denver
id America/Edmonton
id America/Fort_Nelson
id America/Hermosillo
id America/Inuvik
id America/Mazatlan
id America/Ojinaga
id America/Phoenix
id America/Shiprock
id America/Yellowknife
id Canada/Mountain
id Etc/GMT+7
id MST
id MST7MDT
id Mexico/BajaSur
id Navajo
id PNT
id SystemV/MST7
id SystemV/MST7MDT
id US/Arizona
id US/Mountain
```

Comment: this is wrong, since timezone should be of Los_Angeles. i.e PST but what is retreived is MST. The input that is passed is PST

Comment: Since your date only has an Offset Java has no way to know if Daylight Saving is in use or not so it is just giving the UTC-7 time zones without Daylight Saving.

Comment: getting time for Los_Angeles in Java will take into daylight savings and give correct time when requested. That is one of the reason I want to save Los_Angeles rather than UTC-07:00. how would I go about converting now?